# What is the most efficient way find the first time that a column reaches a certain value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
Time       Value
1:00:00    100
2:00:00    110      
3:00:00    100
4:00:00    115
5:00:00    105
6:00:00    130
```

I want to add a new column `Future_time_x` that, for a number `x`, represents the first time at which the future `Value` is greater than or equal to `Value + x%`. The new dataframe would look like this (where `x` is 10):

```
Time       Value    Future_time_10
1:00:00    100      2:00:00
2:00:00    110      6:00:00
3:00:00    100      4:00:00
4:00:00    115      6:00:00
5:00:00    105      6:00:00
6:00:00    130      NaN
```

What is the fastest way to apply this function, if I want to use many values for `x` on each row?

I have tried a brute-force implementation with `df.iterrows()`, but it is no surprise that this method is very slow. It seems that the previous row's results could be used to improve efficiency but this technique would likely lose precision. Thanks!

Comment: This is an O(N^2) problem, I am afraid. You cannot expect a significant improvement, no matter how you attempt top solve it.

Comment: What if the premise of the problem changed slightly, such that `Future_time_x` corresponds to a hard-coded value, i.e. 110 instead of a percent change from the current `Value`? That would allow many values to be forward-filled, correct?